# Slick UnicodeFont displays in different location depending on the screen size?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am using the Slick2D library to draw text. The text draws perfectly, however it is in the wrong location!

I could easily draw it in the correct location, however the problem is that the "correct location" is very different depending on the size of the screen - And my game needs to be able to have the screen size changed.

Here is the render method for the text:

```
 public static void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(orthographicProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    font.drawString(0, 0, "OMG ITS TEXT!", Color.green);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

So, how can I set the text to be in the middle of the screen irrespective of screen size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I haven't used slick2d for a long time but basically you need to find the screens width and height and then divide them by 2 like so...

Paste these at the top of the class in the public variable section

```
int width;
int height;
```

Paste these in the method that has the "GameContainer" reference

```
width = container.getWidth() / 2;
height = container.getHeight() / 2;
```

If you don't have a GameContainer reference then try this

```
width = Display.getWidth()/2;
height = Display.getHeight()/2;
```

These return the centre of the screen... Next you want to use those variables for the drawing of you string like so...

Replace

```
font.drawString(0, 0, "OMG ITS TEXT", Color.green);
```

With

```
font.drawString(width, height, "OMG ITS TEXT", Color.green);
```

Now it should display the words in the centre of your screen... I can't remember where the anchor point for text is but you may have to find the width of the text and divide that by 2 then subtract it from the "width" variable to have perfectly centred text...

Like I said, I haven't used slick for a long long time and I am on my phone so I didn't get a chance to test it...

I hope this clears it up for you

Comment: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getWidth() from the type GameContainer"
What the devil is that meant to mean? I just pasted your code in the render() method above the font.drawString().

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Do you use a GameContainer or an AppGameContainer?

Comment: GameContainer. I directly copy-pasted your code with no changes.

Comment: Try again as I just changed it for you... The getWidth and getHeight are not static methods so you need to have an instance of GameContainer already created to reference them... I think slick does it automatically in a few of the inherited methods

Comment: I cannot create an instance of GameContainer.

I tried:

 GameContainer gameContainer = GameContainer;              
  GameContainer gameContainer = new GameContainer();             
    GameContainer gameContainer = new GameContainer;

Comment: Lol... Please paste your code in your question and I will show you where to place everything

Comment: Paste what code? I have already pasted my code.

Pastebin of current code: http://pastebin.com/EU27KV4P

Comment: Yeh place the whole class file in pastebin so I can see it to help you

Comment: I originally took most of the classes from youtube and modified them, so excuse the word "demo" in the class names. The classes are heavily modified and almost all code in them is now my own.
TextDemo class: http://pastebin.com/p6dh0Gqh
Main class (I initiate the program from here, look at public void main(string[] args) first as that is where the program starts): http://pastebin.com/e8AFhYH5
Maybe Irrelevant classes - Ship: http://pastebin.com/nUAd2jsW CannonBall: http://pastebin.com/XNVtrYFK GameClient: http://pastebin.com/gqydAQp3
Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Check my answer again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14946/discussion-between-savlon-and-user2722083).